# How to use tr command on a string in linux?

Tags: linux, tr

I am trying to use `tr` command on a string inside a text file so that I can replace it with a new line character. For example i have a line like this in my file

```
biological_process      GO:0000001      mitochondrion inheritance       is_a    GO:0048308      organelle inheritance
```

Now I want to convert that to like this

```
biological_process      GO:0000001      mitochondrion inheritance
GO:0048308      organelle inheritance
```

I have used `tr` command before and I thought it would work it but it did now when I try to run it like this

```
test="biological_process      GO:0000001      mitochondrion inheritance       is_a    GO:0048308      organelle inheritance"
echo $test | tr 'is_a' '\n'
b
olog
c
l
proce

 GO:0000001 m
tochondr
on 
nher
t
nce 

 GO:0048308 org
nelle 
nher
t
nce
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

`tr` translates characters, not strings.

```
$ sed 's/is_a/\n/g' <<< "biological_process      GO:0000001      mitochondrion inheritance       is_a    GO:0048308      organelle inheritance"
biological_process      GO:0000001      mitochondrion inheritance       
    GO:0048308      organelle inheritance
$ sed 's/is_a\s\+/\n/g' <<< "biological_process      GO:0000001      mitochondrion inheritance       is_a    GO:0048308      organelle inheritance"
biological_process      GO:0000001      mitochondrion inheritance       
GO:0048308      organelle inheritance
```